# Load html content leads to slow performance (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem I am encountering is that I am trying to keep the application at  high performance around 50 frames per second, but when I navigate through the pages (page1.html, page2.html and page3.html), the application slows down because I believe  that the html pages are running in the background...

What I am trying to achieve is to keep the HTML file that is clicked = display, while holding the rest completely idle, only current page must be visible.

How can I keep the application at high performance? I have tried many JQuery commands such as remove(), empty(), hide(), but none of them improve the performance up to 50 fps.. Highest I have got is 25 fps with remove(), but then I can not get back the content I have removed, very strange.

To get a better overview of the problem I encounter, I have described it below:

If I remove `$("#page1").load("page1.html");` and `$("#page2").load("page2.html");` from the if statement, `page3.html` runs  up to 50 frames per second (fps), this is my goal.

```
 $('[data-target]').on('click', function() {
        var target = $(this).attr('data-target');

        if (target == 1) {

        } else if(target == 2){

        } else if(target == 3){ 
            $("#page3").load("page3.html");
        }
    });
```

But if I add `$("#page1").load("page1.html");` and `$("#page2").load("page2.html");`, then `page3.html` runs up to 15 frames per second, this is very bad and exactly what I am trying to avoid.

```
 $('[data-target]').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');

    if (target == 1) {
        $("#page1").load("page1.html");
    } else if(target == 2){
        $("#page2").load("page2.html");
    } else if(target == 3){ 
        $("#page3").load("page3.html");
    }
});
```

**page1.html:**

```
<div>
  <script src="js/dashboard/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="js/dashboard/highcharts-more.js"></script>
  <script src="js/dashboard/FastCanvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dashboard/fusioncharts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dashboard/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dashboard/fusioncharts.widgets.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Squada+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 

  <style>        @font-face {           
      font-family: "digital";
      src: url("http://joekuan.org/digital.ttf") format("truetype"); }
  </style>
<div id="container" style="width:315px; height:315px; border-radius: 50%; overflow:hidden; margin-top: 220px; margin-left: 479px; position: absolute; z-index: 2;"></div>
<div id="chart-container1" style="margin-left:264px; margin-top: 315px; position: absolute; z-index: 3;"></div>
<div id="chart-container2" style=" margin-left: 365px; margin-top: 315px; position: absolute; z-index: 4;"></div>
<div id="text-area" style="height: 90px; width: 200px; margin-left: 835px; margin-top: 350px; background-color: #1e1e1e; position: absolute; z-index: 9; "></div>
<div id="map" style="margin-left: 845px; margin-top: 360px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 10px; position: absolute; z-index: 10"> </div>
<p id="time" style=" margin-top: 500px; margin-left: 430px; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; z-index: 5; font-family: 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;"></p>
<p id="inside-temp" style=" margin-top: 500px; margin-left: 790px; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; z-index: 6; font-family: 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;">22&deg;C</p>
<p id="temp-sign" style=" margin-top: 468px; margin-left: 315px; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; z-index: 6;font-family: 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif;font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">&deg;C</p>
<p id="liter" style=" margin-top: 470px; margin-left: 418px; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; z-index: 6;font-family: 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">l</p>

<p style=" margin-top: 320px; margin-left: 435px; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; z-index: 6;font-family: 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px;">30</p>
<p style=" margin-top: 382px; margin-left: 435px; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; z-index: 6;font-family: 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px;">15</p>
<p style=" margin-top: 444px; margin-left: 435px; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; z-index: 6;font-family: 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px;">0</p>

<p style=" margin-top: 320px; margin-left: 334px; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; z-index: 6;font-family: 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px;">120</p>
<p style=" margin-top: 390px; margin-left: 334px; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; z-index: 6;font-family: 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px;">90</p>
<p style=" margin-top: 444px; margin-left: 334px; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; z-index: 6;font-family: 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px;">60</p>

<img src="img/icon-temp.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left: 258px;margin-top:470px; position: absolute; z-index: 7">
<img src="img/fuel-icon.png" style="width:17px;height:18px;margin-left: 358px;margin-top:470px; position: absolute; z-index: 7">

<script src="js/dashboard/dash.js"></script>
</div>
```

**page3.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#selectTable").load("ListOfTableSensors.html");
</script>

      <div id="table1"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="table2"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="table3"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="table4"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="table5"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="table6"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="table8"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="table9"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="table10" class="table"></div>
      <div id="table11" class="table"></div>
      <div id="table12" class="table"></div>               
      <div id="selectTable"></div>
```

**js/dashboard/dash.js**

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var chart = new FusionCharts({
      animation: {
                  duration: 800 //animasjonen på speedometeret
                },
        type: 'cylinder',
        renderAt: 'chart-container1',
        id: 'fluid_temperature_water',
        width: '70',
        height: '180',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "",
                "subcaption": "",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "1",
                "lowerLimit": "60",
                "upperLimit": "120",
                "numberSuffix": "",                
                "bgColor": "#000000",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "thmFillColor": "#993333",
                "BgAlpha": "91.9",
                "showTickMarks":"1",
                "showTickValues":"0",
                "baseFontColor":"FFFFFF"
                //"animation":'0' //fjerne all animasjon for cylinderen
            },
            "value": CTS },
        "events": {
            "rendered" : function (evtObj, argObj){
                var intervalVar = setInterval(function () {
                  FusionCharts.items["fluid_temperature_water"].feedData("&value="+CTS);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    })
    .render();
});



FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var chart = new FusionCharts({
      animation: {
                  duration: 800 //animasjonen på speedometeret
                },
        type: 'cylinder',
        renderAt: 'chart-container2',
        id: 'fuel-cylinder',
        width: '70',
        height: '180',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "",
                "subcaption": "",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "1",
                "lowerLimit": "0",
                "upperLimit": "30",
                "numberSuffix": "",                
                "bgColor": "#000000",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "thmFillColor": "#993333",
                "BgAlpha": "91.9",
                "showTickMarks":"1",
                "showTickValues":"0",
                "baseFontColor":"FFFFFF"
                //"animation":'0' //fjerne all animasjon for cylinderen
            },
            "value": FPS },
        "events": {
            "rendered" : function (evtObj, argObj){
                var intervalVar = setInterval(function () {
                  FusionCharts.items["fuel-cylinder"].feedData("&value="+FPS);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    })
    .render();
});


function time_updater(){
  var currentTime = new Date()
  var hours = currentTime.getHours()
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

  if (minutes < 10)
  minutes = "0" + minutes
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = ("<p>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</p>");
}
    setInterval(time_updater, 1000);

    setInterval(function() {
    $("#map").html("Manifold Absolute Pressure:  " + MAP);
    }, 0);
```

Comment: Paste some code from `page123.html`.

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas: `page123.html` consists of `<div>` element, that is responsible for displaying the diagrams. Each page holds a dynamic diagram. As mentioned, the problem is performance. I believe it must be possible to view one page at time while holding the rest idle from the JQuery code.

Comment: loading your html isn't the issue...it's the code running on that html, which you haven't shown

Comment: If you believe that `page123.html` is not a problem then paste some javascript which renders diagrams.

Comment: @charlietfl, I have inserted the content for `page1.html` and `page3.html`. `page2.html` is just based on `<frame>`.

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas, post above is edited.

Comment: so assuming you have a bunch of highcharts, are they being constantly updated? if so could look at destroying the charts on page change and reactivating them when user returns

Comment: @charlietfl, I have already setup an JQuery code for clearing the interval. But the diagram from page1.html is causing me some big issues....

Comment: only suggestion i have is do like angular does...each page uses same container so page changes replace prior content but templates are kept in cache so they don't have to be retrieved each time

Comment: Open developer tools and do some profiling. Show `js/dashboard/dash.js` code.

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas, `js/dashboard/dash.js` is added below the code above.

Comment: What is variable MAP holding?

Comment: It receives some random generated data from an array. Isn't it possible to set method equal to false or something inside JQuery?

Comment: Remove everything that has no meaning or purpose in your code.

Comment: Isolate each case if you are doing a benchmark. Write code. And post another question if stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Increase delay at the bottom of `dash.js`.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#map").html("Manifold Absolute Pressure:  " + MAP);
}, 1000);
```